# Using boolean flag

Tags: java, boolean

I am not sure how I could change the inside of my if statement in the code fragment below to reflect false.

matches is a boolean method

```
if (topPileCard.matches(super.getCardFromHand(i))) {
    tempCardArray[i] = super.getCardFromHand(i); 
}
```

Comment: Add an exclamation mark `!`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to include an exclamation mark `!` at the beginning of the condition statement:

```
if (!topPileCard.matches(super.getCardFromHand(i))) {
    tempCardArray[i] = super.getCardFromHand(i); 
}
```

In Java, `!` can be used to mean *false* or *not*. For example, the `!=` comparator means "not equal to", as opposed to `==` which means "equal to".

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `!`:

```
if (!(topPileCard.matches(super.getCardFromHand(i)))) {
  tempCardArray[i] = super.getCardFromHand(i); 
}
```